# Why is my loop not incrementing?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to take a subset of an mysql statements results from an if statement, and if the last one in the sequence, apply appropriate code.

I want to set up two increments and then if($secondcount > $totalcount) do something else.

MySqlNUMRows won't work as it is a subset, neither will a where clause in this case, that I can see. Can anyone see the cause?

```
$counting = 0;
while($thisrow = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlchangenamesresult))
{   
$change_name = $thisrow['change_name'];

#count the updating results

if(strstr($row['Content_lists'], $change_name) != FALSE)
{
    $counting++;
}   
$totalcount = $counting;

$secondcount = 0;
if(strstr($row['Content_lists'], $change_name) != FALSE)
    {

        if($secondcount > $totalcount)
        {   
            echo '<br>' .$secondcount. '<br>' . $totalcount;
        $sqlinsert .= $thisrow['change_name'];
        $sqlinsert2 .= 'Yes';
        $secondcount++;
        }
        else 
        {
            echo '<br>' .$secondcount. '<br>' . $totalcount;
        $sqlinsert .= $thisrow['change_name'] . ', ';
        $sqlinsert2 .= 'Yes, ';
        $secondcount++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are always reinitializing `$secondcount` with zero for every loop.

Comment: where is ur sql query why havnt you not included it in this code ? is change_name a coulumn in ur table ?

Comment: ?...............................

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the helpful comments. Enricog found the error, I was reinitializing $secondcount with zero for every loop. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

`$secondcount` is `0`, so it cannot be larger than `$totalcount`.

note:

- `!= FALSE` is incorrect
- `$totalcount` always equals `$counting`. why have to variables?
- `$secondcount++;` is in both branches.. move it out of the branch body.